# GTK+ progressbar: text activate the propertie "show-text"

Tags: text, progress-bar, gtk

Working on Win XP with GTK+ (2.22) with the "progressbar" widget when i change the "text" propertie this puts in true the "show-text" propertie. So, giving a value no null to "text" make it visible whatever the value of "show-text". On the other hand, changing "show-text" don´t affect the value of "text". That´s a normal behaviour or something is wrong?. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

That's normal behavior, at least if I understand your question right. (I misunderstood at first, because I was in a hurry, but it's still normal behavior.) The `show-text` property was deprecated. In the past, it was used to turn on and off a text display of the progress bar's percentage. This has been replaced by a facility for displaying any sort of text you like in the progress bar, which is the `text` property. In short, the `show-text` property in GTK 2.22 doesn't control the visibility of the `text` property.

To make things confusing, but ultimately better, in GTK 3.0, a new `show-text` property has been added which *does* do what you expect: control the visibility of the text.

Comment: Sorry but sounds some "strange" this behaviour to me? May be i don´t really understand the function of "show-text". I'd guessed that "show-text" activate/deactivate the fact of show (or not) the text, beyond the text itself. You say that´s wrong?. What´s then the "real" function of "show-text" ?

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry. I'll expand my answer to explain more.

Comment: Ok. Answer very clear. Good explanation of something such tangled!. Thanks you, ptomato.